# How to use an expression in a join between two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables. In the 1st table (`transaction`) there are 2 columns called `supplier_code` and `local_commodity_code`. In the 2nd table (`local_feed_commodity_map`) there are two columns called `local_commodity_code` and `local_commodity_desc`.  In 1st table, the `local_commodity_code` field is made by concatenating the `supplier_code` from 1st table and `local_commodity_code` from the 2nd table.
I split the concatenated column by using the following code:

```
SELECT
SUBSTR(T.LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE, 1, INSTR(T.LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE,'~')-1) LOCAL_COM_CODE
FROM OYSTER_WEB3.TRANSACTION T
```

So, I have the column named `local_com_code` after splitting.

Now I want to join these two tables using the newly generated column (local_com_code) and the local_commodity_code column from the 2nd table. How can I do this only using SELECT statement because I don't have permission for create, insert or update table.

Comment: This isn't how you ask questions on Stack Overflow. Please reflect on [writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page (and [Ask] page) soon. You're committing a number of cardinal sins. We don't care a hoot about urgency; you should not claim urgency in your question. It raises hackles and earns lots of down-votes really fast (no, I haven't yet).  You need to design your question carefully, to make it interesting. You should also format code (SQL in this case) carefully, using the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it for readability.

Comment: Whoever designed the schema for these two tables needs to be taken out to the woodshed and ... made to repent of their sins.  That's an appalling design — as described, it is worse because it is pointless as well as appalling!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT L.*, T.*
  FROM (SELECT Supplier_Code,
               Local_Commodity_Code,
               SUBSTR(LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE, 1, INSTR(LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE,'~')-1)
                      LOCAL_COM_CODE
          FROM OYSTER_WEB3.TRANSACTION
       ) T
  JOIN Local_Feed_Commodity_Map L
    ON L.Local_Commodity_Code = T.Local_Com_Code
```

Oracle has an aversion to the SQL standard 'AS' keyword in some locations, so I've not used it anywhere to maximize the chances of the code working.

However, as I noted in a comment to the question, this is an appalling piece of schema design and should be fixed. It is ludicrous to pessimize all queries that have to work between these two tables by requiring the use of SUBSTR and INSTR like that.  The Local_Commodity_Code in the Transaction table should be identical to the Local_Commodity_Code in the Local_Feed_Commodity_Map table so that both the primary key and the foreign key columns can be properly indexed (and referential integrity enforced).

Comment: 2 more tables needs to be joined with this query.how will it be done?

Comment: Dunno; it depends on how the two extra tables join to the ones already in the query. I expect it will involve the keyword JOIN twice more. Don't go changing the question after you've been given answers; people don't like it much.  Adding two more tables into a query is routine query modification, but you have to know how they're connected to the tables in the query.

Comment: @user3068762: Would you mind to accept this answer, if it helped you solving your initial question?